# Button Command in WPF MVVM Model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I have two UserControls in my MainWindow and UserControl2 has 2 Listboxes,Texboxes and Buttons.When i write some text in TextBox and press Button it should add into the ListBox.Can somebody help me with the code,i'm new to WPF and MVVM

This is my XAML code

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf_MVVM.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf_MVVM" 
    Title="Voxer" Background="SlateGray" Height="420" Width="550">


<Grid>
    <local:UserControl1 HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <local:UserControl2 HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="150,29,0,0"/>




</Grid>
```

This is my UserControl1.Xaml code

```
<UserControl x:Class="Wpf_MVVM.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
<Grid>
    <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="310" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Margin="0,40,0,0">
        <ListBoxItem>Name 1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Name 2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Name 3</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Name 4</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Name 5</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Name 6</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
    <Label Content="Conversations" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Height="40" Width="150" FontSize="20" Background="SkyBlue"/>
    <Button Content="Create New Chat" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,350,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150"/>

</Grid>
```

This is my UserControl2.Xaml code

```
<UserControl x:Class="Wpf_MVVM.UserControl2"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Height="Auto" Width="390">
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="listbox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="310" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
    <ListBox Name="listbox2"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="310" Margin="200,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180"/>
    <TextBox Name="tb1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="200,310,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130"/>
    <TextBox Name="tb2" Height="40" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="" Margin="10,310,245,0"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" Name="btn1" Content="Send" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="330,310,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" />
    <Button Command="{Binding SendControlCommand}" Name="btn2" Content="Send" Height="40" Margin="145,310,200,0"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: 1. You're missing the point of grids I think ... you should have rows or columns (or both), and have the second control in a different one.
2. To which listbox you want to add what, from which button?

Comment: I don't see any question here. You are supposed to ask a question related to the problems you have with this. We won't just write your code for you.

Comment: @user2889489 ok, so, what have you tried, and what's your code for those methods? (`ButtonCommand` & `SendControlCommand`).

Comment: @user2889489 what do you mean it didn't work? what didn't work. Are your methods actually called when you press the button? how are you binding to the sources of the lists?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds to me that you're stabbing in the dark ...
You say you're using `MVVM` and `WPF`, but I think you should revise your background on those topics first ...

Basically, your View should bind to properties on the `ViewModel`.

Usually you'll want to have an observable collection that would be the source for the list box, and the on your XAML do something like

```
<ListBox Name="listbox_name"  ... ItemSource="{Binding ListPropertyName}/>
```

(I'm assuming you have a property of type `ObservableCollection` named `ListPropertyName`, obviously you'll name it something else according to your needs)

Then, the commands. Once you have:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" Name="btn1" Content="Send"... />
```

It means you need to have an `ICommand` property in your view models code, called `ButtonCommand`:

```
public ICommand ButtonCommand{ get; private set; }
```

In your constructor you could then write:

```
ButtonCommand= new RelayCommand<object>(Execute_YourMethodHere);
```

Now, when you hit the button, your `Execute_YourMethodHere` is run.

This is where you'll probably want to add the object to your `ObservableCollection` (assuming you have used `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so the View will know your collection changed), and that's really about it ...

Comment: "obviously you'll name it something else according to your needs" <3

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget about **`DataContext`**?
In behind code, you should add this line: 
`this.DataContext = new YourViewModel();`

Can you show your CommandMethods?

Answer (score 0):

You forget the bind an ItemsSource to the lists in the second xaml. If you want to do it in a right way with MVVM, you need two ItemsSource properties, two relaycommands and two string properties in the view model. In the command action simply add the appropriate text to the appropiate list's ItemsSource.

You also need to aware of INotifyPropertyChanged, ObservableCollection and ICommand to make it work.